# How can I set up Drupal on an amazon box using an RDS as the database?

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, amazon-rds, amazon-ec2

So I set up the RDS and the server where my Drupal installation is based but I'm running into trouble installing Drupal.

I get this following error: 
[image: Drupal installion issue]

I haven't got these issues before but seeing as it's an RDS I'm not sure if I need to do something completely different than any usual issues.

Any ideas?

Thanks,

Comment: I fixed the File System error anyway. Working on the rest of them. Just not sure how to connect Drupal to the RDS

Comment: You configure the mysql connection settings to the RDS instance like you would any remote database server.